# Xcode renames my files with a "~" when I edit them

Tags: xcode

I am having a very strange thing happen to me when trying to work on any of my Xcode projects. All the projects that do this are apps that have already been published on the App Store. When I try to edit any of the files, .storyboard, .h or .m, Xcode will rename them by adding a "~" at the end of the name, for instance, "Main.storyboard" becomes "Main~.storyboard". This will cause Xcode to say that they have dissipated. I can get them back by going to the file in Finder and just deleting the "~" from the name. This problem is preventing me from working on or updating any of my apps. What is going on?

Update: A reinstall of Xcode did not help the problem. Here is a pic of the error. [image: error message]

Clicking "resave" allows me to work without the file disappearing but I will still get these errors every few minutes.

Comment: This sounds like a Xcode bug. Have you tried to reinstall Xcode?

Comment: The twiddle versions are just temporary backups. - What version of Xcode is this?

Comment: Sorry for the super late reply on this. I just moved across the country..  I am using version 5.1.1 and I am attempting a reinstall right now to see if it resolves it.